# Zoom functionality on Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, zooming, jframe

Here is the scenario , I  have an swing application used to show bookings ,we're using J Frame to show the information(some sort of images , booked ,unbooked) ..i have an requirement that when the user clicks on J Frame , The J frame itself should zoom itself,...
However ... i dont have any clue how to implement this using swing ?

Any help would be appreciated??

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "The J frame itself should zoom itself"? Can you please explain.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure about what what you are asking.But since you asked to zoom the JFrame, I suppose this is for readability, and I'd like to point out a different way. If you wish to zoom for better readability, that means you have a lot of information in the frame, In this case, I'd suggest you to organize the informations in your frame accordingly and use a [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) rather than going for a zoomed frame.